# Extracting text from a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a little bit of trouble completing this code chunk. I feel like I'm close, but I can't just make the needed leap.

I have two text chunks `"He came home last night to"` and `"his wife of several years"`. I also have a larger text which is `"Before he came home last night to Melinda Gates, his wife of several years who loves him dearly"`. I want to be able to extract the name `"Melinda Gates"` from the second text.
I am able to write a code chunk which extracts "Melinda Gates" by using the pattern

```
pattern = fr"{re.escape(before_text)}(.*?){re.escape(after_text)}"
```

which combines the first two texts; i.e. `before_text = "He came home last night to"` and `after_text=his wife of several years`.
However, the `before_text` or `after_text` can change significantly, e.g. `after_text=his wife of several years who grew up in Poland` or `before_text = "While he was drunk and came home last night to"`, in which case my regex fails.
The nearest texts are guaranteed to be the same, however. 

How can I adopt the regex to still extract the text "Melinda Gates" when the texts change like this? I'd appreciate any ideas.

I have a temporary solution which extracts the last 3 words in the `before_text` and the first 3 words in the `after_text`, but I'm thinking a regex solution is probably a better solution.

Comment: Define "nearest"? Is it always 3 or can it be larger or smaller? Please lay out some examples and desired results.

Comment: Also please write a more specific title. See [ask] for tips on that.

Comment: If "nearest" means the largest number that gets a result, you could just work your way down: try all words, then try nearest x, then nearest x-1, etc.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but `He` doesn't match `he` unless you have case-insensitive matching turned on. Do you? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Using regex to parse natural language might not be the best idea. Use [spacy](https://spacy.io/) or something similar.

Comment: Assuming `before = "He came home last night to "` and `after = "his wife of several years"`, match `r"(?<=\b{before}\b)[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z](?=,? +\b(?<={after})"`, which after substitution becomes `(?<=\bHe came home last night to \b)[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z](?=,? +\bhis wife of several years\b)`. `(?<=\b{before}\b)` is a *positive lookbehind*; `(?=,? +\bhis wife of several years\b)` is a *positive lookahead*. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l0vqjR/1)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for. Are you just trying to get the text between `last night to` and `his wife of several years`? In that case just use those strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
### you can use re.split() for that. I am not familiar with Spacy.
```

```py
    before_text1 = "He came home last night to"
    after_text1 = "his wife of several years"
    before_text2 = "While he was drunk and came home last night to"
    after_text2 = "his wife of several years who grew up in Poland"
    txt1 = "he came home last night to Melinda Gates, his wife of several years who loves him dearly"
    txt2 = "While he was drunk and came home last night to Melinda Gates, his wife of several years who grew up in Poland "
    print(st)
    st1 = "".join(re.split(fr'\W+{after_text1.lower()}.*', "".join(re.split(fr'^.*{before_text1.lower()}', txt1.lower())))).title()
    print(st1)
    st2 = "".join(re.split(fr'\W+{after_text2.lower()}.*', "".join(re.split(fr'^.*{before_text2.lower()}', txt2.lower())))).title()
    print(st2)
```

```
 Melinda Gates
 Melinda Gates
```